# How can I bulk download images from a photo gallery-like website?

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

Is there anything like NeoDownloader for Ubuntu that I can use to download all the images from a link? Or is it somehow possible to download the directory from a web server containing photos?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**BeautifulSoup**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) can be of great help.

With the Help of [**Amith KK**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054390/get-text-within-single-quotes-from-an-html-file?noredirect=1#comment1724777_1054390) its been of great help for me and since then, used for some other little tricks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox then get the Download helper add-on.  It is a good Firefox add-on  DownThemAll. It can list and download all of a certain file type, and it have some advanced settings.

DownThemAll lets you download all the links or images contained in a webpage and much more: you can refine your downloads by fully customizable criteria to get only what you really want.

Give it a go, I hope it does the trick.

<sup>Source:Firefox</sup>